# how to show accordion-group based on items in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to show an `accordion-group` of `angular-ui` only if an `array` contains items. this can be changed dynamically.
I tried to use `ng-show` but since the array starts without items it is not displaying at all and it is not re-rendered again once items are added. I add a plunker for it: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IiI2DfB3FSlEbVdAnsni?p=preview)

Should I make the `ng-show` re-render somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely something in the `accordion-group` directive that prevents the `ng-show` from working as you want. I haven't digged deeper into it though.

You can always wrap the `accordion-group` in an extra div and put the `ng-show` there instead:

```
<div ng-show="items.length > 0">
  <accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
    <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
  </accordion-group>
</div>
```

Demo: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2p7vgVUtQdJ1ejS5Dy1A?p=preview)